# Ionic 3 *ngFor inside an element of array

Tags: loops, ionic3

Is there a way to loop in `*ngFor="let x of data[0]"` ?

It gives me :

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

But if I do something like : `*ngFor="let x of data" and print {{x.name}}` it works .

So the point is In `data[0]` I have an element "el" that is another array.

So I want to do something like : `let x of data[0].el`

Comment: Can you show an example of `data`

Comment: Please provide example data

Comment: @cristian i solve your problem please check and confirm me..

Answer (score 1):

what about converting your assigning data[0] to an array?

in controller class level

```
newData: any[] = [];
```

in function

```
newData=data.json();
```

and then

```
*ngFor="let x of newData"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using ***ngFor**

Your post will say this type of data

```
 this.data=[{el:[{f:'fa1',l:'la1'},{f:'fa',l:'la'}],surename:'sarkar'}];
```

so in **.html** we need to change in ***ngFor**

```
*ngFor="let x of data[0]['el']
```